# Accessing Google Photos after Authentication to Google Apis not working (Error 403 Forbidden)

Tags: wpf, windows, google-api, google-authentication, google-photos-api

I have an issue accessing Google Photo API, 
I've authenticated successfully in a indows Desktop application following [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows) guide but when I get the authentication Token, I cannot access the API I receive a 403 Forbidden as shown bellow :

```
{StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
```

{
  Vary: X-Origin
  Vary: Referer
  Vary: Origin
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="44,43,39,35"
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Accept-Ranges: none
  Cache-Control: private
  Date: Mon, 20 Aug 2018 19:50:07 GMT
  Server: ESF
  WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/", error="insufficient_scope", scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.appendonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.sharing"
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
}}

I can see this is related to scopes, and I went through Google's documentation, but I don't know where to make use of these scopes for it to work properly, please can someone help me ?